# How to set above_fermi/below_fermi in sympy's second quantization module?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to evaluate complicated commutators of fermionic creation and annihilation operators by using sympy's secondquant module. But I do not understand how `above_fermi` and `below_fermi` is used properly to get the correct outcome. [In the documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/secondquant.html) they show the following example:

```
from sympy.physics.secondquant import Fd, F
a = symbols('a', above_fermi=True)
i = symbols('i', below_fermi=True)
p,q = symbols('p,q')
comm = Commutator(Fd(p)*Fd(q),F(i)); comm
>>> Commutator(CreateFermion(p)*CreateFermion(q), AnnihilateFermion(i))
comm.doit(wicks=True)
```

with the outcome

```
-KroneckerDelta(i, p)*CreateFermion(q) +
 KroneckerDelta(i, q)*CreateFermion(p)
```

The outcome makes perfect sense, but it changes if I set `above_fermi` and `below_fermi` in the symbols differently. I would have expected that `above_fermi` is set to True if the symbol is used for a creation operator, while `below_fermi` is used for a symbol of an annihilation operator. However, this does not seem to be the case: If I define `p` and `q` as

```
p = symbols('p', above_fermi = True)
q = symbols('q', above_fermi = True)
```

the result of the very same commutator becomes zero, which is not the correct result obviously. Defining all variables without the `above_fermi`, `below_fermi` boolean values, the final expression will be not simplified at all. So what does `above_fermi` and `below_fermi` mean exactly and how is it used properly?

I need e.g. the result of the commutator

```
Commutator(Fd(i)*F(j), Fd(k)*Fd(l)*F(m)*F(n))
```

with which I want to check my handwritten solution. But without knowing how to define the symbols properly I get several different results and I do not know which of them is correct.

I appreciate your help!(: